# I need to connect my Django live app database to a live sap b1 database server

Tags: mysql, django, heroku, sapb1

I need to connect my database in my live Django app which I deployed on Heroku to a live SAP B1 database, i.e when something is created, updated or deleted in my database it will automatically be done in the SAP B1 database.

I've no experience at all with SAP software but I was told by the client that they can't make an API for their server which I would send the data to and they take care of their database, instead they want me to integrate the two databases together. Is there any solution on how to do this?

PS: both will be running a Mysql DB

Comment: Why add `postgresql` tag and use mysql in your question?

Comment: My Django app database is postgresql

Comment: You shouldn't develop and test on a DBMS that is different to the one used in production

Comment: Connecting Django to MySQL is trivial, but it sounds like that's not actually what you want to do. You are trying to integrate your entire Django application, including its PostgreSQL database, with an external service somehow, right? Can you [edit] your question and provide more explanation of exactly what you want to do? Please read [ask].

Comment: Okay, will do that.

Comment: For information, SAP Business One (B1) can run only on MS SQL Server or HANA database, not MySQL, so I don't understand "both will be running a Mysql DB"...